# Two SSL connections at the same time on Uno WiFi rev 2

Tags: networking, tcpip, arduino-uno-wifi

So I want to have one persistent SSL connection to a cloud server (Azure IoT Hub) to upload telemetry and another SSL connection to a server to perform a simple GET request every 30 minutes.

I've setup my first connection and telemetry is successfully sent, then I connect to the second server, I get a response, close the connection, but my first connection to Azure IoT Hub crashes.

I haven't found any information online on how many simultaneous SSL connections the Arduino Uno WiFi Rev. 2 supports nor any guidance on how to use more than 1 SSL connections. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have had some problems with using two sockets simultaneously with WiFiNINA versions > 1.3, see https://github.com/arduino-libraries/WiFiNINA/issues/87 . Maybe it's the same problem. Which WiFiNINA version are you using?

Comment: @ocrdu yes I think it's the same problem. I was using version 1.6.0.

Comment: Edit: Firmware version is 1.3, library version is 1.7

Comment: If things work OK when you use firmware 1.4 and this alternative library: https://github.com/ocrdu/WiFiNINA , then it's the same problem 8-).